# file downloading using jsp but not readable

Tags: java, servlets, file, jsp

I am trying to download files using jsp but then downloaded files are not readable.
Suppose if i download pdf files then it can not opened,if i download jpg files then it can not opened and similarily for the video files too.

Please point out the mistakes where i have made

```
    <%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import= "java.io.*" %>
<%
try{
String txtFileNameVariable="movie.mp4";
String locationVariable="../webapps/y/";
String PathVariable="";
//txtFileNameVariable = request.getParameter("fileVariable");
//locationVariable = request.getParameter("locationVariable");
PathVariable = locationVariable+txtFileNameVariable;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try{
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(PathVariable));
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
fnfe.printStackTrace();
}
File f=new File(locationVariable, txtFileNameVariable);
String fileType = txtFileNameVariable.substring(txtFileNameVariable.indexOf(".")+1,txtFileNameVariable.length());
if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) {
response.setContentType( "text/plain" );
} else if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
response.setContentType( "application/msword" );
} else if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
response.setContentType( "application/vnd.ms-excel" );
} else if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
response.setContentType( "application/pdf" );
} else {
response.setContentType( "application/octet-stream" );
}
String original_filename = txtFileNameVariable;
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + original_filename + "\"" );
try{
int anInt=0;
while((anInt=bufferedReader.read())!=-1)
out.write(anInt);
}catch(IOException ioe){
ioe.printStackTrace();
}
}catch(Exception e){
out.println("This is the Error " +e.getMessage());
}
%>
```

Comment: Locate the errors yourself, then report them on Stack Overflow.  We (and them) don't serve as a compiler.

Comment: One think I can say [don't use Java code in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: @Jamal i have already compiled

Comment: @javaprogrammer: Okay, but it still belongs on SO since the code is not working.  If you have specific errors, then those should be mentioned to better assist you.

Comment: @Jamal no compile time error,no runtime error,no errors at all just the file is not readable

Comment: @javaprogrammer: That's fine, then.  Just be aware that they may not be so willing to just search your code for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

- Don't use `FileReader`, that's meant to be used for char streams, where undesireable transformations could happen due to default charsets and the like. Binary streams are the correct choice for your case.
- Your first try-catch sentence doesn't handle the error apropriately, you only print the stacktrace, but your code will probably throw a NullPointerException at the first reference to bufferedReader.
- Maybe this is a simplified version of your JSP, but just in case: have you noticed that you are not validating the user input? (I guess you get the filename from a request parameter, as you have commented a line where the filename is taken from the request) what if, say, you receive something like "../../../etc/passwd"? this is a security issue.
- Scriptlets are deprecated, consider using JSTL tags or custom ones.
- You are opening a stream (bufferedReader) but you never close it.

Anyway, this is a version of your JSP using `InputStream` instead of `Reader`, I haven't fixed the other issues I mentioned (that is your task):

```
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import= "java.io.*" %>
<%
try{
    String txtFileNameVariable="movie.mp4";
    String locationVariable="../webapps/y/";
    String PathVariable="";
    //txtFileNameVariable = request.getParameter("fileVariable");
    //locationVariable = request.getParameter("locationVariable");
    PathVariable = locationVariable+txtFileNameVariable;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
    try{
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileinputStream(PathVariable));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    File f=new File(locationVariable, txtFileNameVariable);
    String fileType = txtFileNameVariable.substring(txtFileNameVariable.indexOf(".")+1,txtFileNameVariable.length());
    if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) {
        response.setContentType( "text/plain" );
    } else if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
        response.setContentType( "application/msword" );
    } else if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
        response.setContentType( "application/vnd.ms-excel" );
    } else if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
        response.setContentType( "application/pdf" );
    } else {
        response.setContentType( "application/octet-stream" );
    }
    String original_filename = txtFileNameVariable;
    response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + original_filename + "\"" );
    try{
        int anInt=0;
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        while((anInt=bufferedInputStream.read())!=-1)
            output.write(anInt);
        output.flush();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    out.println("This is the Error " +e.getMessage());
}

%>
```

Comment: ,i do not find any errors either compile time or runtime.

Comment: @javaprogrammer Sorry, I didn't understand your comment

Comment: i dont have any errors while compiling or running. Just the downloaded files are not readable

Comment: No one is saying that you have compilation errors, I just reviewed your code and commented my observations (and BTW fixed your original problem)

Comment: ... and the fact that you have no compilation problems doesn't mean that your code doesn't have issues.

Comment: i dont think your answer is useful